# Activating bean validation in TomEE application specifically

Tags: bean-validation, apache-tomee

I am trying to activate bean validation in TomEE, but on the application level, not on the container level.

According to [the documentation](http://tomee.apache.org/examples/bean-validation-design-by-contract/README.html), the correct property to set is `org.apache.openejb.default.system.interceptors = org.apache.openejb.bval.BeanValidationAppendixInterceptor`. Setting this in the `system.properties`, i.e. on container level, works fine. However, setting this in `application.properties` does not seem to enable the bean validation.

Is there a specific reason why this should not be allowed? Or is it even a bug in TomEE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the configuration is only read at container level.

Note this is removed from coming TomEE 7 (class is there but implementation is a noop) cause bean validation 1.1 supports it in a standard manner.